# Redirect output for SVN post-commit hook

Tags: bash, svn, redirect, hook, post-commit

Whenever I execute my subversion post-commit hook it runs successfully but I don't get any output to the console.

My post commit hook calls another script and the other script provides important user feedback.  I tried redirecting this way but it didn't work:

```
sh /path/to/my/script.sh arg >&1
```

Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send stdout to the user when running SVN pre-commit hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318104/how-to-send-stdout-to-the-user-when-running-svn-pre-commit-hook)

Comment: @chepner I noticed this refers to pre-commit hooks, do the same rules also apply to post-commit scripts?  I assume they do, but the answer on that link you provided is very specific about it being pre-commit hook related.

Comment: I am not positive, but the accepted answer seems to imply the same rules apply to all hooks. It's as if the hook is invoked as `whatever-hook > /dev/null`, that is, every command in the hook inherits `/dev/null` as its standard output.

Comment: Note also that (I think) Subversion hooks run on the machine where the repository lives, which is not necessarily the machine where the working directory is and `svn ci` is run.

Comment: Thanks @chepner this was very helpful information